# What are some of best books in Galois theory?

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory

I am thinking to learn Galois theory on my own. I have basic knowledge about field theory. So which book I should read? Please suggest some of the best book on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **Galois Theory** by *Ian Stewart*;

one of the best book for beginners

Comment: Garner is also excellent. These two books in conjunction is how I learned the basics - and it was wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Dummit and Foote may not be the best book for Galois Theory (Chapters 13-14) but it contains numerous examples.